# DataGridView: Pass by Value or Reference?

Tags: c#, datagridview, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I think of DataGridView's as being memory hogs. Is it better to pass by value a datagridview or by reference? Should it even be passed at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing it by value or reference isn't going to matter from a memory stand point, because the DataGridView is a reference type, not a value type.

Comment: How come you can use the ref keyword to pass a datagridview? A reference of a reference? Seems strange.

Comment: @Brian If you pass a reference type by reference, then you're passing the reference that is being used by the caller.  So, for example, if you assign the parameter to a new DataGridView inside the function, the caller would see their objects become a new DataGridView, which may or may not be what you want.  If you pass by value instead, then you're passing a copy of the reference, so assigning a new DataGridView to the parameter would have no effect on the caller.

Comment: @Brian reference/value types have no relation with ref out modifiers. the modifiers are applied to variables and not the values they hold. A ref modifier on a variable that holds a reference type means that by passing that variable a copy of the reference is not made but instead the calling function will use the same variable as the caller

Answer (score 3):

The type `DataGridView` is a reference type and hence it's not possible to pass the **object** by value.  You can pass the **reference** to the object by value but that is a very small (typically pointer sized) value.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Joseph's answer, All passing it by value does is create a new variable on the call stack in the called methods stack frame, and copy the address (in the Heap) of the DataGridView object into that variable for use by the called method.  All this does is prevent the called method from assigning a new DataGridView object's address to the variable in the ***caller*** (calling method), and thus changing *which* dataGridView the caller will be pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

1. You won't (need to) pass any Control very often
2. You cannot pass the object itself at all.
3. You can only pass the reference to an object, and doing so by value (the default) or by reference (ref parameter) has no impact on memory usage. It is a design decision but usually,  certainly for Controls, you will pass the reference by value.

Comment: Is there a way around having to pass the DataGridView to a method that needs information or performs a function on the datagridview, such as setting column styles? There must be some ingenious way to do it.

Comment: No, there is no way around that. And there is no need for it.

Comment: You **aren't** passing the DGV. You are passing a reference, which is tiny.